# Is Address input box along with pick your location in a same filed in mobile will be User friendly?

Tags: usability, android, user-centered-design

I am designing a food delivery app. I want to make it as minimal and user friendly as possible. In the image below we have two options to input the address:  [image]

**1-** In the left side image, there is a box to put the address manually and below it there is a link to use the current location of of the user.

**2-** In the right side image, inside the input box, there is an option to put the address manually as well as an option for picking the current location, too.

My question is, which one is better to use from the perspective of User Experience? Will the second option convey the features adequately for the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first option is better. A user can easily understand from where he/she can add it's current location. You can use the second screen if you are creating an application for limited and system-known(trained) users. But here, users are wide and also might possible new(who has never used any food delivery app or app which has add current location feature)

Also, you can give suggestion list of addresses when a user starts to type an address in a textbox.

Answer (score 1):

The first option. Most people won’t know what the centre location icon means. Also, the second choice is not apparent that the icon is clickable because the colours are the same.